# sql server is "value" equal to "value "

Tags: sql-server, blank-line

I have two Tag values in the same column.

```
value1 = "(Massachusetts)"
value2 = "(Massachusetts)" + CHAR(10)
```

I'd like to convert the new line version to `"value "` (with a blank space) but I get a primary key duplication error.

> "Violation of PRIMARY KEY constraint 'Contact.Tag'. Cannot insert duplicate key in object 'dbo.Contact.Tag'. The duplicate key value is (id_num_removed, id_num_removed, (Massachusetts) ).
>   The statement has been terminated"

This is the statement I'm running.

```
update [Contact.tag]
SET TAG_NAME = '(Massachusetts) '
where
    instance_id = 97986
    and contact_id = 93941676
    and TAG_NAME = '(Massachusetts)' + CHAR(10);
```

I have tried a version with replace and get the same error.

```
UPDATE [blah].[dbo].[Contact.Tag]
SET TAG_NAME = REPLACE(TAG_NAME, CHAR(10), ' ')
where TAG_NAME LIKE '%' + CHAR(10) + '%'
```

It seems like SQL server thinks that `"value" = "value "`

Any suggestions?

Comment: You can use a binary collation, but that has other problems. Yes, it is a [documented feature](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/316626) that strings which differ by no more than trailing blanks compare equal. And of course a newline is *not* considered a trailing blank, because... that would just be silly, I guess? *\*cough\**

Comment: Do you have duplicate tags? Try SELECT * FROM [Contact.tag] WHERE TAG_NAME LIKE '(Massachusetts)%';

Answer (score 0):

Sql server will not consider Trailing spaces. If you want to duplicate it you better prefix the space character instead of suffix.

`update [Contact.tag] SET TAG_NAME = '(Massachusetts) '
where instance_id = 97986 and contact_id = 93941676 and TAG_NAME =Char(10)+ '(Massachusetts)'`